# Project created from App Engine Console comes with less features compared with project created from Cloud Console

Tags: google-app-engine

When I create a new Application from App Engine Console https://appengine.google.com/,
the application also appears on Cloud Console https://cloud.google.com/console#c=l

However, clicking into the project shows that only these features are included:

- App Engine
- BigQuery
- Cloud Datastore

Compared with Project created directly from Cloud Console:

- App Engine
- Compute Engine
- Cloud Storage
- BigQuery
- APIs
- Cloud Datastore
- Cloud SQL

That leads to problem that App Engine project is missing access to many features and there seems no obvious way to add them back later.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found how to do this:

- Go to https://appengine.google.com/
- Open your app
- Open Administration / Application Settings
- Click the button in the "Cloud Integration" section

Comment: nice, finally google had created the last piece of the puzzle

Answer (score 3):

1,This only implies that when you create an application from app engine console, it directly creates **3** types of projects: app engine app, datastore instance and big query(i think you need to enable the api first) with the **same project id**. This does not mean you cannot use the other features. It only means you need to separately enable them and give project ids.

2, If you create a project from cloud console, then it will automatically create projects under all the **7** different categories with the **same project ID**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried assigning the same ID to the APIs project, but it tells me that the ID is not available. Is there any downside to the projects not being linked?