# "You have not created any kinds yet." error when creating cloud SQL instance

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-datastore

I originally created a project with the API console, let's call it projectA. I then applied to have it whitelisted for PHP deployment and it was granted access. Then I tried to create a cloud sql instance via cloud.google.com and I get the weird error message:

You have not created any kinds yet.

Now when I go back to the api console, the projectA is not there anymore. However, I can still see and modify projectB. In the cloud.google.com interface, projectB has has 7 services available:

1) app engine
2) compute engine
3) cloud storage
4) BigQuery
5) APIs
6) cloud datastore
7) cloud SQL

So, I can easily create a cloud SQL instance for projectB. However, on projectA on cloud.google.com I only see 3 services:

1) app engine
2) BigQuery
3) cloud datastore

I'd like to know what happend to my other services. Where they blocked or disabled when my project was whitelisted for php deployment, is there some other configuration setting I'm missing, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is difference in the default number of services that are automatically created when you create a project using the two approaches, but the missing services can still be manually enabled. [Check this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622142/project-created-from-app-engine-console-comes-with-less-features-compared-with-p/16678022#16678022)

Comment: Pretty confusing with app engine, api console, and cloud console. I wish they would all just merge into cloud! But thanks, this pointed me in the right direction and I was able to enable the additional services.