# What's the relationship between the App Engine application dashboard and the Google API console?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api

I'm trying to manage a few App Engine applications (and projects?).   I'm confused by the terminology.  All of my applications appear in Google App Engine application dashboard [0], and some but not all appear in the Google API console [1].  What's the relationship between these two consoles?  What's the difference between an 'application' in [0] vs a 'project' in [1].  Why does the billing information seem consistent across both?

My current best guess: an App Engine application is one layer below an API console project.  To connect an application with a console project, you a) create an API project [2] and then b) configure your App Engine application to use it [3].  Is that right?  If so, why and/or how is billing information shared across projects and applications?  Does a project inherit an application's billing information?

Any guidance appreciated!  Thanks!

```
[0] appengine.google.com
[1] code.google.com/apis/console
[2] developers.google.com/console/help/#creatingdeletingprojects
[3] https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is good. A project created in [cloud console](https://cloud.google.com/console) can be considered as a master project as this will have corresponding app engine and api projects. If you create a project in app engine, then you need to further link it to a cloud project by using the option `Add Project` under `Cloud integration` within `Application settings` tab. All projects, be it app engine or api, that are linked to the same master cloud console project will have synching of billing information. You can read this post to understand the [initial difference between projects created from app engine and cloud console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622142/project-created-from-app-engine-console-comes-with-less-features-compared-with-p/16678022#16678022)

Answer (score 0):

With the Google App Engine application dashboard you administer your application / the projects you have build.

With the API console you can expose an interface to a web service in the same way as Google exposes an interface (API).

When you use app engine you can build an application, which can expose API's using the API console. See  this doc : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api

An app engine application / project (appid) can have more than one WSGI or CGI app, when you use Python. An app here is like a main for routing incoming requests. I am not familiair with GAE GO, Java or PHP.